# Make this faster. (Min, Max in same iteration using a condition)

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, max, min

I would like to ask if/how could I rewrite those lines below, to run faster.

*(-10000, 10000) is just a range where I can be sure my numbers are between.

```
    first = 10000
    last = -10000

    for key in my_data.keys():
        if "LastFirst_" in key:  # In my_data there are many more keys with lots of vals.
            first = min(first, min(my_data[key]))
            last = max(last, max(my_data[key]))

    print first, last
```

Also, is there any pythonic way to write that (even if that wouldn't mean it will run faster)?

Thx

Comment: Should really be on Code Review.

Comment: You can use `float("inf")` and `float("-inf")` for your min and max instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `*` operator to unpack the values:

```
>>> my_data = {'LastFirst_1':[1, 4, 5], 'LastFirst_2':[2, 4, 6]}
>>> d = [item for k,v in my_data.items() if 'LastFirst_' in k for item in v]
>>> first = 2
>>> last = 5
>>> min(first, *d)
1
>>> max(last, *d)
6
```

Comment: Is it not overkill to use hash sets when we're just looking for the first and last?

Comment: Unless the contained data types aren't hashable, `set`s are ideal here, because we don't care about duplicates and `set`s are fast.

Comment: `set`s are fast to do membership testing, but that doesn't seem to be in play here.  To calculate `min` or `max` the entire list must be iterated anyway.

Comment: There's the cost of putting every element into a hash table. It's clever, but neither more expressive nor more efficient than using lists and generators. What advantage does using a hash give?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be:  `d = set(v for k,v in my_data.items() if 'LastFirst_' in k)` Seems like union with empty set is not needed.

Comment: It could, but I'm using `list` dictionary values here. If they were `tuple`s it would work.

Comment: Totally missed that part of the question. Sorry.

Comment: Actually, that gives a `set` of `tuple`s, not a `set` of the `tuple`s' values, so I don't think that would work.

Comment: If I'm reading your intention right, you could simplify your `d` assignment thus: `d = set(el for k,v in my_data.items() if 'LastFirst_' in k for el in v)`

Answer (score 0):

```
values = [my_data[k] for k in my_data if 'LastKey_' in k]
flattened = [item for sublist in values for item in sublist]
min(first, min(flattened))
max(last, max(flattened))
```

or

```
values = [item for sublist in (j for a, j in d.iteritems() if 'LastKey_' in a) for item in sublist]
min(first, min(values))
max(last, max(values))
```

I was running some benchmarks and it seems that the second solution is slightly faster than the first.
However, I also compared these two versions with the code posted by other posters.

```
solution one:  0.648876905441
solution two:  0.634277105331
solution three (TigerhawkT3):  2.14495801926
solution four (Def_Os):  1.07884407043
solution five (leewangzhong):  0.635314941406
```

based on a randomly generated dictionary of 1 million keys.
I think that leewangzhong's solution is really good. Besides the timing shown above, in the next experiments it's resulting slightly faster than my second solution (we are talking about milliseconds, though), like:

```
solution one:  0.678879022598
solution two:  0.62641787529
solution three:  2.15943193436
solution four:  1.05863213539
solution five:  0.611482858658
```

Itertools is really a great module!

Comment: This doesn't appear to include the `"LastFirst_" in key` condition.

Comment: what about the ' if "LastFirst_" in key:'?

Comment: Calling `my_data[k]` is an unnecessary key lookup. Should probably use `items` or `iteritems`.

Comment: Did you test my `set` solution or my current one?

Comment: Your current one. I guess that it appears a bit slower due to repeated unpacking...

Comment: I guess unpacking is slower, even though it's more Pythonic.

Comment: Me neither ... It must be some internal reason, although listcomp are one of the fastest things in Python...

Answer (score 0):

You could use some comprehensions to simplify the code.

```
first = min(min(data) for (key, data) in my_data.items() if "LastFirst_" in key)
last = max(max(data) for (key, data) in my_data.items() if "LastFirst_" in key)
```

Comment: This requires checking "LastFirst_" in key twice as many times.

Comment: True.  But OP doesn't mind. "(even if that wouldn't mean it will run faster)"

Comment: Sorry, brain skipped the last sentence. First sentence asked for faster.

Comment: Doesn't include the initial `first` and `last` values.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: It doesn't need to. "(-10000, 10000) is just a range where I can be sure my numbers are between."

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I could only guess.

Answer (score 0):

The `min` and `max` functions are overloaded to take either multiple values (as you use it), or one sequence of values, so you can pass in iterables (e.g. lists) and get the min or max of them.

Also, if you're only interested in the values, use `.values()` or `itervalues()`. If you're interested in both, use `.items()` or `.iteritems()`. (In Python 3, there is no `.iter`- version.)

If you have many sequences, you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to make them one long iterable. You can also manually string them along using multiple `for` in a single comprehension, but that can be distasteful.

```
import itertools

def flatten1(iterables):
    # The "list" is necessary, because we want to use this twice
    # but `chain` returns an iterator, which can only be used once.
    return list(itertools.chain(*iterables))

# Note: The "(" ")" indicates that this is an iterator, not a list.
valid_lists = (v for k,v in my_data.iteritems() if "LastFirst_" in k)
valid_values = flatten1(valid_lists)
# Alternative: [w for w in v for k,v in my_data.iteritems() if "LastFirst_" in k]  

first = min(valid_values)
last = max(valid_values)

print first, last
```

If the maximum and minimum elements are NOT in the dict, then the coder should decide what to do, but I would suggest that they consider allowing the default behavior of `max`/`min` (probably a raised exception, or the `None` value), rather than try to guess the upper or lower bound. Either one would be more Pythonic.

In Python 3, you may specify a `default` argument, e.g. `max(valid_values, default=10000)`.

Comment: This seems even faster than recursives answer because it checks for the key only once.

Comment: Doesn't include the initial `first` and `last`, though.

Comment: You are assuming that the minimum and maximum elements are in the dict, though.

Comment: @Markon, I added them in, but just removed them. Will add my rationale.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_data = {'LastFirst_a': [1, 2, 34000], 'LastFirst_b': [-12000, 1, 5]}

first = 10000
last = -10000

# Note: replace .items() with .iteritems() if you're using Python 2.
relevant_data = [el for k, v in my_data.items() for el in v if "LastFirst_" in k]
# maybe faster:
# relevant_data = [el for k, v in my_data.items() for el in v if k.startswith("LastFirst_")]

first = max(first, max(relevant_data))
last = min(last, min(relevant_data))

print(first, last)
```

Comment: You're using `*` and `max()` improperly. This will result in an error.

Comment: `max()` returns a single value, so unpacking it doesn't work.

Comment: Now I see: `relevant_data` is a `list` of `list`s, so you're finding the max/min `list` in that, then finding the max/min of those and `first`/`last`. That may give strange results, as it seems that `list` comparisons are evaluated based on the first element (i.e., `[4,1] > [3]` is `True` but `[1,4] > [3]` is `False`).

Comment: I see. I've flattened the list first now, should generalize better.